# Is 1 a unit modulus of itself?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

We say that 1 is a unit modulus of itself if there exist $ a \in\Bbb Z$ such that $ 1a \equiv 1 \mod 1$. This statement is equivalent to finding the set of $a$ such that $ 1| (1a-1) $, and the answer is the set of all integers. However, the seemingly contradictory part is that we know that $ 1 | x $ for all $x \in\Bbb Z$, thus we obtain $1a \equiv 0 \mod 1$. So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Mod 1, everything is equivalent to zero.

Comment: In this case I think that $0\equiv 1 \; (mod\; 1) $

Comment: Is there a concrete way to show this?